# jQuery selector contains brackets

Tags: jquery

I have a select list with the following markup:

```
<select name="dropdown[users]">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">2</option>
</select>
```

I want to get the value of the select list option.

how is this done is jQuery?

I have tried:

```
$('select[name="dropdown[users]"]');
```

This doesn't seem to work

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `val()`:

```
var selectValue = $('select[name="dropdown[users]"]').val();
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/92tcy/)

The fact the name has `[]` in it is not a factor as you have enclosed the attribute value in quotes.

If you removed the quotes, you would need to escape the braces with `\\`, like this:

```
var selectValue = $('select[name=dropdown\\[users\\]]').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

to obtain the value you must use the .val() method

### http://jsfiddle.net/xPnvE/1/

```
$('select[name="dropdown[users]"]').change(function(){
  alert($(this).val());
});
```